# When does it make sense to store the result of a comparison versus recalculating a comparison in terms of speed?

Tags: java, performance, memory-management, comparison, processing-efficiency

I'd like to have a solid understanding of when (ignoring available memory space) it makes sense to store the result of a comparison instead of recalculating it.  What is the tipping point for justifying the time cost incurred by storage?  Is it 2, 3, or 4 comparisons?  More?

For example, in this particular case, which option (in general) will perform better in terms of speed?

Option 1:

```
int result = id.compareTo(node.id);

return result > 0 ? 1 : result < 0 ? -1 : 0;
```

Option 2:

```
return id.compareTo(node.id) > 0 ? 1 : id.compareTo(node.id) < 0 ? -1 : 0;
```

I tried to profile the two options myself in order to answer my own question, but I don't have much experience with this sort of performance testing and, as such, would rather get a more definitive answer from someone with either more experience or else a better grasp of the theoretical elements involved.

I know it's not a big deal and that most of the time the difference will be negligible.  However, I'm a perfectionist, and I'd really just like to resolve this particular issue so that I can get on with my life, haha.

Additionally, I think the answer is likely to prove enlightening in regards to similar situations I may encounter in the future wherein the difference might very well be significant (such as when the cost of a comparison or memory allocation is either unable to be incurred or else complex enough to cause a real issue concerning performance).

Answers should be relevant to programming with Java and not other languages, please.

I know I've mentioned it a few times already, but PLEASE focus answers ONLY on the SPEED DIFFERENCE!  I am well aware that many other factors can and should be taken into account when writing code, but here I want just a straight-forward argument for which is FASTER.

Comment: Think first of readability, then of performance!

Comment: @ewernli
True, but the answer that I'm looking for is really only geared towards one priority: performance.  I understand that, in actual applications, I would of course take into account other (arguably more important) priorities.  But thanks for the reminder!

Comment: you still can try to measure the execution time, call test metho a million of times, measure with nanoTime(), and warm up he vm with 1 million calls of both methods. Look that the methods are not optimized away: sum up the result of each method calls, and finalybprint outbthe result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experience tells me that option 1 should be faster, because you're making just one call to the compare method and storing the result for reuse. Facts that support this belief are that local variables live on the stack and making a method call involves a lot more work from the stack than just pushing a value onto it. However profiling is the best and safest way to compare two implementations.

The first thing to realise is that the java compiler and JVM together may optimise your code how it wishes to get the job done most efficiently (as long as certain rules are followed). Chances are there is no difference in performance, and chances are also that what is actually executed is not what you think it is.
One really important difference however is in debugging: if you put a break point on the return statement for the store-in-variable version, you can see what was returned from the call, otherwise you can't see that in a debugger. Even more handy is when you seemingly uselessly store the value to be returned from the method in a variable, then return it, so you may see what's going to be returned from a method while debugging, otherwise there's no way to see it.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "strie-in-variable version"?  I apologize if that's a dumb question, but I was unable to turn up anything that would define the term via a quick google search.  
Also, would you be willing to explore why this is the case in your answer?

Comment: It was a typo - I've edited my answer to correct it (I'm typing this in on an iPhone while watching TV :) )

Comment: In that case, I would be happy to both accept this answer and upvote if you would include an argument related to which option is better in terms of speed in addition to the other useful information you've provided!  If you still maintain that hidden compiler implementation details obfuscate the issue then just say which option would be best assuming a completely dumbed-down compiler that "simply" translates code on a word-by-word basis. :)

Comment: You must always measure. Optimization isn't a guessing game.

Comment: I've given my opinion of which option should perform better in my edited answer. Also I recommend reading and following Alex's comment to your question.

Comment: Thanks for continually following-up with the information that I requested! While I may indeed try to implement a more thorough battery of tests to be certain, I'm very willing to accept this answer and am convinced for now that it is accurate!

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 cannot be slower than 2, if the compiler optimizes then both could be equal, but then still 1) is more readable, compacter, and better testable.

So there is no argument for Option 2).

If you like you could change to `final int result = ....`
Although i expect that the compiler is so clever that the final keyword makes no difference in this case, and the final makes the code a bit less readable.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't considered using the final keyword. Could you explain further what the intended optimization (albeit perhaps unnecessary) is?

Comment: When you look in the docu of java you will found that a final local variable is one that can be asigned only once, such that it cannot change anymore later. The intention of java for this is to give the compiler a hint fot better optimization. (But depending on the compiler, it might analyze that the variable is not changed anymore and treat it like if you have explictily defined it as final)

Answer (score 0):

**option1** one always preferred one ,because here the real world scenarion

----->ok lets

1) thread exceution at  id.compareTo(node.id) > 0 ? 1 , in this process some other thread

changes the value of node.id right after `id.compareTo(node.id) > 0 ? 1` before going to

`id.compareTo(node.id) < 0 ? -1 : 0` this check ,  the result not  identical?

performance wise option1 has more performance when there is bit of functionality exisist in checking.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer for grammar and spelling in order to make it a bit more clear?  I think I see where you're going, but then again...I'm not really sure that I do given the mentioned difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

> When does it make sense to store the result of a comparison versus recalculating a comparison in terms of speed?

Most of the time, micro-optimizations like option #1 versus option #2 don't make any significant difference.  Indeed, it ONLY makes a significant performance difference if:

- the comparison is expensive,
- the comparison is performed a large number of times, AND
- performance matters.

Indeed, the chances are that you have *alrady* spent more time and money *thinking* about this than will be saved over the entire useful lifetime of the application.

Instead of focussing on performance, you should be focussing on making your code readable.  Think about the next person who has to read and modify the code, and make it so that he/she is less likely to misread it.

In this case, the first option is more readable than the second one.  THAT is why you should use it, not performance reasons.  (Though, if anything, the first version is probably faster.)

Comment: the last sentence is incomplete

Comment: Sorry, but the question quite clearly asks for the speed comparison and NOT any suggestions or information related to other issues. I just wanted either a theoretical answer based in logic or else an experimental answer based in mathematics, not a lecture on the importance of taking into account other factors when writing code (things of which I'm already well aware). Again, I appreciate the concern, but your answer is not appropriate in this very particular context.

Comment: @sweetname: there is no logical or mathematical answer. The closest you can get is try it and either study the assembly language that the jitter produces, or run it under a cycle-level interpreter like kachegrind. What I do is run it in a realistic program (regardless of language) and if some random pauses catch it there, fix it.